# How to turn values of a column into new individual columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello everyone I am trying to convert a categorical variable which is a  column named Educational Group and has values like

```
State  |  Educational Group    | No of Persons |
-------+-----------------------+---------------+
  A       Below Metric                123
  A       metric/secondary            456
  A       diploma                     789
  A       graduate and above       101112
  A       post graduate            131415
  B       Below Metric                145
  B       metric/secondary            467
  B       diploma                     564
  B       graduate and above          987
  B       post graduate               875
```

I want this to be converted as

```
State  |  Below Metric_ NO of persons  | Metric/Secondary_No of persons | Diploma_No of Persons|  ...
-------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------+
A                 123                           456                           789
B                 145                           467                           564
```

and so on for all states and all educational levels.

Is it possible to do in SQL? Actually I did the same in Python using pivot function and it worked pretty well and now I the same to be done in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I want to convert this
https://ibb.co/L15m2sS

into this https://ibb.co/9tLpk7V

Comment: You are looking for a `PIVOT`. There are plenty of resources out there. Just google it and you'll find a solution.

Comment: But pivot is making just rows into new columns but I want row values to be merged with column values into new columns for each row value

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned `PIVOT` should do the trick.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable
) AS SourceTable PIVOT(AVG([No_of_Persons]) FOR [Educational_Group] IN([Below Metric],
                                                         [metric/secondary],
                                                         [graduate and above],
                                                         [post graduate])) AS PivotTable;
```

Online demonstration using your table on [db<>iddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ac7eb731e846b76acd2e2a1618134aa5).